# How to apply border-top: x; with Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Is there a way to add border-top with tailwind? Before you say it, i did look at the documentation and searched on google. I don't need border-top-width i need exactly border-top. Also its ok to use just in time css.

Comment: `border-t border-red border-dashed`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="h-20 w-20 bg-gray-300 flex justify-center items-center">
  <div class="border-t-4 border-black h-5 w-5 bg-white mt-"></div>
</div>
```

Live example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/aUPhlY2DrZ

Those are the properties you are searching for:

```
class="border-t-4 border-black"
```

And here the documentation if you need more details:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#individual-sides